# How do I make a background static in HTML and CSS?

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, css, mobile

Im making a mobile website with jQuery Mobile, CSS and HTML and Ive set a background picture on all of the different pages.
It works fine on those pages which contains a small amount of text. But one page contains text in the amount that you have to scroll down to read.
On that page the background resizes and you can only see like half of it.
If I want a static background that always looks and stays the same regardless of how I scroll, what should I do?

Comment: Post the current css code for the background.

Comment: As I said Im using jQuery Mobile so the code for the background lies right in the html. It looks like this:

<div data-role="page" id="start" style="background: transparent url('Images/phoneWallpaper.jpg') no-repeat; background-size: cover;">

Comment: Why dont you try repeating the image on Y-Axis if the image is smiple repeatable image. on the other hand you can fix your background by fixing a div with `position:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;background:url('ur image url');background-repeat:no-repeat` by using the above you dont even need to repeat the image and render your text on the div you made.

Answer (score 1):

modified as mentioned by '@Rob W'
`background-attachment:fixed` should do the job.

Comment: `background-attachment: fixed;`

Comment: @RobW `background-attachment: fixed` is the answer, so submit it as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

You have to either change the `background-size` property (look at specs or [css3.info](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/)) or add `repeat` instead of `no-repeat`. Depends on the effect you want to get.

Comment: Its a grey background with a logo. So I dont want it repeating. The best thing would be if it stayd static and only the text scrolled down.

Comment: Then use `background-size` and `background-position` :)

Comment: YEs I do but I dont know what properties to apply. What position property and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
background: url(path-to-image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size: cover;
```

If you're using a background pattern, instead of `no-repeat` use:
 `repeat`, `repeat-x` or `repeat-y` depending on your needs.
The `background-size` property is up to your discovery. I like it!